# Will variables inside of scope-blocks be garbage collected once the scope exists in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, memory, scope, garbage-collection

For example, will this `data` variable be garbage collected instantly?

```js
{
  const data = new Array(10000);
}
```

...and if so, does this mean using scope-blocks in JavaScript can be a practical method of localizing short-lived data? I know this shouldn't be high priority or anything, but I'm just curious.

Comment: JavaScript garbage collection is controlled by the runtime engine (not the JS code). While some engines might allow you to configure behavior ahead of runtime, that's not standardized.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I trigger JavaScript's garbage collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032928/can-i-trigger-javascripts-garbage-collection)